# canceling http request in angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, promise, httprequest, angular-promise

We are making an HTTP request based upon user input. So each time the user inputs a character, an HTTP request is kicked off. The issue we are having: the user will enter `ABC` and then enter `ABCD`. `ABCD` will respond before `ABC`. Thus, the displayed results do not match `ABCD`. They match `ABC`.

Below is our current solution. We are rejecting all promises that have not been resolved. This seems to me to be an anti-pattern. Is there an approach to this that will result in better performance, readability, or better functionality?

```
function cancelPreviousSearchRequest(previousSearchRequest) {
        if(previousSearchRequest) {
            previousSearchRequest._defer.resolve();
        }
    }

function getPVendors(typed, subTypes) {

    var pVendorsDefer = $q.defer();
    var pVendorsPromise = pVendorsDefer.promise;
    $http.get(SERVLET_CONTEXT + RestConstants.masterDataIntegrationSearchByPvendorName(typed, subTypes), {timeout: pVendorsPromise})
        .success(function(data){
            var result = _.get(data, '_embedded.paymentVendors', []);
            pVendorsDefer.resolve(result);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            if(data != null) {
                growl.error("Service error occurred while retrieving Payment Vendors");
           }
            pVendorsDefer.reject();
        });

    pVendorsPromise._defer = pVendorsDefer;
    return pVendorsPromise;
}
```

**NOTES FROM COMMENTS:**

We are doing a debounce already: `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 150 }"`

Comment: The most simple solution is to wrap the request with debouncing function with optimal delay, also good for performance.

Comment: We would still have the problem with a debounce. It may happen less often but will still happen. Any other ideas?